# Passing a javascript argument into D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently making a scatterplot matrix in D3. My data point structure looks like this:

```
      function plot(p) {
      var cell = d3.select(this);

      x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
      y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

      // Data points
      cell.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d[p.x]); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[p.y]); })
      .attr("r", 3)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.species); });
  }
```

I also have a javascript function:

```
      function create(columnsplit) {

      cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
      .data(cross(traits, traits))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
      .each(plot);

      cell.call(brush);

  }
```

where plot is assigned. However, I would like to replace the hardcoded d.species with the columnsplit argument that I have in my create function (unless d.species doesn't work like I originally thought). How exactly would I do this?

Here is how I the traits for the datum d are being created, from what I can understand:

```
domainByTrait = {},
      traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (d) { return d !== columnsplit; }),
      n = traits.length;

traits.forEach(function (trait) {
              domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d[trait]; });
          });
```

I am using this as my template: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663

Thanks

Comment: `I would like to replace the hardcoded d.species with the columnsplit argument that I have in my create function` What do you mean exactly?  Why can't you just do it?

Comment: I would need to set it to d."whatever column is defined in columnsplit", but because the "." makes it a literal attribute, I can't just go d.columnsplit, because then it would look at the current datum and look for an attribute called columnsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to access the property named the value of "columnsplit".  To do this you just use the indexer notation for accessing properties:

```
d[columnsplit]
```

In other words, the `d.species` syntax is equivalent to `d["species"]` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)).